# Как отрезать расширение у названия файла?

Tags: php

Как отрезать расширение у названия файла? например файл называется restore.php так вот надо отрезать "php" и вывести.

Comment: Советую вам воспользоваться всё же решением c `pathinfo()`. Регулярки - это не то.

Answer (score 6):

```
$file = '/var/www/restore.php';
echo pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция примерно на 40% быстрее, чем pathinfo()

```
public static function removeFileExtention(string $fileName): string
{
    return substr($fileName, 0, strrpos($fileName,'.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/\.\w+$/', '', ' restore.php'); // restore
```

**UPD:** Второй вариант:

```
echo basename('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php'); // lib.inc
```

Comment: @KiTE, у файла /tmp/conf.d/tra-ta-ta что отрежет ?

Comment: У `/tmp/conf.d/tra-ta-ta` регулярка `/\.\w+$/` ничего не отрежет. `\w` - это тоже что и `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: я так понял вы отрезали что перед расширением и вывесли, а мне надо не название файла и именно расширение, вы немогли бы подправить код ?

Comment: Тоже ведь проблемы с *нормальными* (для \*nix) именами, ведь **любые** символы кроме '/' и '.' **могут** быть в расширении.

Т.е регулярка д.б. какая-то другая. Она должна сопоставляться с самой правой точкой и всем кроме '/' после этой точки.

Comment: @oldzas, расширение это то, что начинается с последней точки в имени файла. Если имя файла `lib.inc.php`, то его базовое имя `lib.inc`, а расширение `.php`.

В любом случае - [регулярки в помощь][1].

  [1]: http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: нашел решение:  substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);

Comment: @oldzas, тоже посмотрите на /tmp/conf.d/tra-ta-ta

Comment: @avp, да, вы правы. Тогда, как вариант, `/\.[^\.\/]+$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'example.docx';
echo substr($str,strripos($str,'.')+1); // docx
```

Comment: Откройте для себя волшебный мир pathinfo -- и сразу отпадёт необходимость создавать собственные велосипеды.

Comment: Что будет, если в названии две точки?

Comment: Strripos - находет последние вхождение символа